# Selenium Python: Empty cache in headless mode for chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, caching, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to empty the cache in headless mode using the following code:

```
def clear_cache(driver, timeout=60):
"""Clear the cookies and cache for the ChromeDriver instance."""
    driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//settings-ui').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

It works on normal mode but when i activate the headless mode, i get the following error:

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//settings-ui"}
(Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.102)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome settings contains the shadow element so I guess you will be not able to click on element directly by using XPath. You can use JavaScript as below to achieve the same.

```
javaScript = "document.querySelector("body > settings-ui").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-basic-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#basicPage > settings-section:nth-child(8) > settings-privacy-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-clear-browsing-data-dialog").shadowRoot.querySelector("#clearBrowsingDataConfirm")"
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', javaScript)
```